# as_mut().unwrap(): Cannot infer lifetime due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Rust lifetimes confuse me again. I'm trying to return a mutable reference to a boxed object I own. Here is my problem simplified:

```
pub trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

pub struct Bar {
    foo: Option<Box<Foo>>,
}

impl Bar {

    pub fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Box<Foo> {
        let foo_ref = self.foo.as_mut();
        foo_ref.unwrap()
    }

    pub fn set_foo(&mut self, value: Box<Foo>) {
        self.foo = Some(value);
    }
}
```

I get these errors, which I don't really understand:

```
   Compiling testproject v0.0.1 (file:///home/virtlink/projects/orion/testproject)
src/lib.rs:15:17: 15:25 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
src/lib.rs:15         foo_ref.unwrap()
                              ^~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:15:9: 15:25 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the method call at 15:8...
src/lib.rs:15         foo_ref.unwrap()
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:15:9: 15:16 note: ...so that method receiver is valid for the method call
src/lib.rs:15         foo_ref.unwrap()
                      ^~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:13:44: 16:6 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 13:43...
src/lib.rs:13     pub fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Box<Foo> {
src/lib.rs:14         let foo_ref = self.foo.as_mut();
src/lib.rs:15         foo_ref.unwrap()
src/lib.rs:16     }
src/lib.rs:15:9: 15:25 note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected `&mut Box<Foo>`, found `&mut Box<Foo>`)
src/lib.rs:15         foo_ref.unwrap()
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `testproject`.
```

I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a case of lifetime elision and the default object bounds backfiring in a painfully invisible way.

The errors are downright opaque as it is, which is not good. If you replace the `.as_mut().unwrap()` with the comparable `match` statement:

```rust
match self.foo {
    Some(ref mut foo) => foo,
    None => panic!(),
}
```

things become a little clearer:

```
a.rs:13:34: 13:37 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&mut Box<Foo>`,
    found `&mut Box<Foo>`
(lifetime mismatch) [E0308]
a.rs:13             Some(ref mut foo) => foo,
                                         ^~~
a.rs:11:44: 16:6 note: the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 11:43...
a.rs:11     pub fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Box<Foo> {
a.rs:12         match self.foo {
a.rs:13             Some(ref mut foo) => foo,
a.rs:14             None => panic!(),
a.rs:15         }
a.rs:16     }
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Now we know that what is happening is a lifetime mismatch in somewhere in the type `&mut Box<Foo>`, that an anonymous lifetime does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime. There are two lifetimes in that type; with no type elision, that type is `&'a mut Box<Foo + 'b>`. Remember that with a trait object, you still need to indicate how long the trait object can last for, hence `'b`. In the most common case, `Box<Trait>` is equivalent to `Box<Trait + 'static>`, which indicates that the trait object cannot contain any non-static references. (Without this guarantee, memory safety would be violated.) In your struct definition, the lifetime of the trait object is inferred as `'static` in this manner.

However, the elided lifetime in `Box<Trait>` is not always interpreted as `'static`. If it is contained in a reference, then the required lifetime is shrunk to that, i.e. `&'a Box<Trait>` is interpreted as `&'a Box<Trait + 'a>`.

Therefore, the full elision-free signature of your method is actually this:

```rust
pub fn foo<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Box<Foo + 'a>;
```

Now why this doesn’t work I’m not clear on; I would have thought that a `&'a mut Box<Foo + 'static>` (which you have) could be coerced to a `&'a mut Box<Foo + 'a>`, but apparently this is not the case; it *might* be a bug in variance handling (rejecting code that should be legal) or it might not be, I’m not sure. I don’t see why the anonymous lifetime #1 should be needing to outlive the static lifetime, that error feels like it’s handling the lifetimes back to front.

Anyway, what you actually wanted was to be returning a `&'a mut Box<Foo + 'static>`. So just write the `'static` out explicitly and all is hunky‐dory:

```rust
pub fn foo(&mut self) -> &mut Box<Foo + 'static> {
    self.foo.as_mut().unwrap()
}
```

Another solution is to require in the definition that a type implementing `Foo` must always be `'static`. Then `Box<Foo + 'a>` would be obvious nonsense for an `'a` not necessarily as great as `'static`, and it gets sensible and knows that it’s got to be `'static`. (Any lifetime constraint on the trait overrides the default object bounds.)

You can read more about the default object bounds in [RFC 599](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0599-default-object-bound.md).

Comment: This is great, thank you! I didn't know about the trait lifetime and had tried `pub fn foo<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Box<Foo>` to no avail. How can I require a type implementing `Foo` to be `'static`? I tried `trait Foo<'static>` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe a better alternative to forcing `'static` would be to add a lifetime parameter to `Bar`: `pub struct Bar<'f> { foo: Option<Box<Foo+'f>> }`.

Comment: @rodrigo: it all depends on what you want and need. Adding a lifetime parameter is strictly superior for what it allows you to do, but if you don't need that ability its slight increase in verbosity should be avoided. I imagine that most cases will be fine with `'static`.